# if value is '{{user->experience}}' add class 'active' on label laravel or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

How to add 'active' on label class like  after checking value from database with laravel {{$user->experience}} . if value is Entry-Level add 'active' on label class .

Here is my HTML Content

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            
            <label class="btn btn-success active" for="option1">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option1" value="Student">Student
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-primary" for="option2">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option2" value="Entry-Level">Entry-Level
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-info" for="option3">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option3" value="Mid-Level">Mid-Level
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-default" for="option4">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option4" value="Senior-Level">Senior-Level
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-warning" for="option5">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option5" value="Manager">Manager
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-danger" for="option6">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option6" value="Director" >Director
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>
        
        </div>
```

Here is my css

```
.btn span.glyphicon {         
  opacity: 0;
}
.btn.active span.glyphicon {        
  opacity: 1;       
}
```

My laravel value fetching

```
{{$user->experience}}
```

Mysql 'user' Table

```
 - id      name         experience

 - 1       john         Entry-Level
```

Website : [JsFeed](https://www.jsfeed.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ternary operators` to achieve your goal.

```php
<label 
    class="btn btn-success {{$user->experience == 'Entry-Level' ? 'active' : ''}}"
    for="option1"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to achieve this or you can use If.

```
{{$user->experience == 'Entry-Level'?'active':''}}
```

Here is an example.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

            <label class="btn btn-success {{$user->experience == 'Entry-Level'?'active':''}}" for="option1">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option1" value="Student">Student
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-primary" for="option2">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option2" value="Entry-Level">Entry-Level
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-info" for="option3">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option3" value="Mid-Level">Mid-Level
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-default" for="option4">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option4" value="Senior-Level">Senior-Level
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-warning" for="option5">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option5" value="Manager">Manager
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-danger" for="option6">
                <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option6" value="Director" >Director
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator to toggle the class active and the checked attribute

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-success {{$user->experience == 'Student'?'active':''}}" for="option1">
        <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option1" {{$user->experience == 'Student'?'checked':''}} value="Student">Student
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-primary {{$user->experience == 'Entry-Level'?'active':''}}" for="option2">
        <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option2" {{$user->experience == 'Entry-Level'?'checked':''}} value="Entry-Level">Entry-Level
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-info {{$user->experience == 'Mid-Level'?'active':''}}" for="option3">
        <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option3" {{$user->experience == '>Mid-Level'?'checked':''}} value="Mid-Level">Mid-Level
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-default {{$user->experience == 'Senior-Level'?'active':''}}" for="option4">
        <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option4" {{$user->experience == 'Senior-Level'?'checked':''}} value="Senior-Level">Senior-Level
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-warning {{$user->experience == 'Manager'?'active':''}}" for="option5">
        <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option5" {{$user->experience == 'Manager'?'checked':''}} value="Manager">Manager
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-danger {{$user->experience == 'Director'?'active':''}}" for="option6">
        <input type="radio" name="experience" id="option6" {{$user->experience == 'Director'?'checked':''}} value="Director" >Director
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: do a var dump of each ternary operator, if they return all false then your value are not the same, you may have some white spaces in your db

Comment: glad to have helped